# Joomla 1.6 articles for registered users

Tags: joomla

Im using joomla 1.6 and when I create an article limited to registered users, it dissapears from the parent category for not registered (or not logged in) users.

Is there a way to show just the article title to any user, so when he tries to view it display a registration window ?

Answer (score 1):

J1.6 does not give you control over what parts of a component to show to different user levels, only whether or not the user level can access the component at all. In order to accomplish what you want you will either need an additional component, or possibly through a template override. You'd need to change the permissions for articles to be accessible to the public then add in a little code to the template to hide content unless a user is logged in.

Make a copy of joomla16/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php and put it in joomla16/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_content/article/default.php. Then add this code:

```
STUFF YOU WANT ALL USERS TO SEE
<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) {
    echo "<p>You must be logged to see this content</p>";
} else {
STUFF YOU DONT WANT ALL USERS TO SEE
} ?>
```

I did a quick test with this code and it works pretty well. http://internextion.com/joomla16/

Answer (score 1):

Enter in users manager, go to options up ahead and in the Users Configuration check the guest group. Must be public.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that can do that for you.

e.g.

- [Content Restriction](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/15946)
- [Login to Read More](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/17006)
- [read less text](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/article-elements/articles-summary/12432) *(alert: I'm the author)*